# Is there a function to compare a string to a larger string?

Tags: c#, string, compare

A better way to explain my question is like this

List the names of someone whose names contain a given string. For example, if the given string is "John,", the system will display the names of every person whose name contains "John", such as "John Smith", "Elton Johns", and "johnny H".

I couldn't explain it in the question and trying to find what I'm looking for on Google when I can't phrase is right is difficult

Comment: I guess you mean to say if a string `Contains` in another string but you need to expand the context you are searching this in database or you have a List of string or ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring

Comment: `bool IfExists = str.IndexOf("John", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                           >-1;`

Comment: @Habib you had the correct answer, why did you delete it?

Comment: @ErenErsönmez,  I think its a duplicate, I marked it as dupe, and deleted the answer.

Comment: Which culture do you want to use for this? The culture the local user prefers? Or `InvariantCulture`?

Answer (score 2):

If your search is case-sensitive, you can use `Contains`:

```
var name = "John Smith";
if(name.Contains("John"))
{
   // Name contains John
}
```

Or, to get *all* the names that contain *John*:

```
var names = new string[] {"John Smith", "Bob Smith", "Frank"};
var results = names.Where(n => n.Contains("John"));
```

If you want to ignore the case, you can convert both strings to lowercase:

```
var results = names.Where(n => n.ToLower().Contains("john"));
```

You could also implement your own case-insensitive `Contains` function as an extention method:

```
public static bool Contains(this string value, string substr, StringComparison c)
{
  return value.IndexOf(substr, c) >= 0;
}
```

Then use:

```
var results = names.Where(n => n.Contains("John", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: +1 for `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 0):

```
IList<string> lst = new List<string>();

lst.add("John Smith");
lst.add("Elton Johns");
lst.add("mark");
lst.add("jones");
```

now to get the names contains `"John"`

```
var resultList = lst.Where(x => x.Contains("John")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Linq

```
    private static List<String> GetNames(List<string> names ,string name)
    {
        return names.Where(x => x.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower())).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We have [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) and [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx).

> String.Contains: Returns a value indicating whether the specified
>   String object occurs within this string.
>
> String.IndexOf: Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence
>   of a specified Unicode character or string within this instance. The
>   method returns -1 if the character or string is not found in this
>   instance.

`Contains` is case sensitive so, if you want to give "John" and find "johnny H" it would better use `IndexOf`

```
var key = "John";
var names = new[]{"John Smith", "Elton Johns", "johnny H"};
foreach(var name in names)
if(name.IndexOf(key, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1) {
    // Name contains the key
}
```

If you want to use you Contains should convert both name and key to upper or lower with an appropriate culture info.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should also consider uppercasing ( *.ToUpper* ) and sanitizing ( *.Replace(",", "")* ) your strings before cheching them with *.Contains*, otherwise "johny H" wouldn't contain "John,".